# PhpStorm preview reload change option at settings does not work

Tags: php, phpstorm, live-preview

Option "Reload page in built-in preview" does not work, no matter if I choose "On save" or "On change" (need this one). Pass to option:     Settings -> Tools -> Web Browsers and Preview (the option is in bottom)

[image]

As you see in image below, I echoed 2 five times changes still didn't appear on preview, that's why need the reload option to get working.

[image]

Deployment settings

[image]

[image]

Comment: 1) What kind of file are you trying to preview? Show more details on that. 2) Does the preview works at all (e.g. when invoked manually)?

Comment: @LazyOne Problem with preview is in php files: preview doesnt update when i change code, so preview needs to be closed and then opened again to see result. Example in added by me to post second image. 
But it is fine with just html files, preview updates every change in css or other thing
(and the option in settings, that makes preview update, doesnt work - the main question of post)

Comment: It works for me (On Save) if I have no Deployment entry marked as Default (so PhpStorm is launching PHP's web server to handle that). But if I have it configured (even if it's "In Place" type) and it web requests are handled by my IIS, then it does not work indeed. No clues on why.

Comment: Change the setting, then restart PhPstorm, that sometimes does the trick.

Comment: @Grumpy It was the first thing to do

Comment: @RidddleWrong So what are your deployment settings?

Comment: @LazyOne added to post as asked

Comment: @RidddleWrong Try removing Web server URL. This should force the IDE to use built-in web server for Preview where reload works.

Comment: @LazyOne in that case it writes 502 Bad gate way, I removed it fully, and then removed only after http//: ,    result 502 Bad gate way

Comment: @RidddleWrong In such a case I do not have any other suggestions (based on the info at hands).

Answer (score 1):

The `Reload page in built-in preview` feature only works for the PhpStorm built-in web server.
When you create a default deployment configuration with `Web server URL` specified, PhpStorm renders it through the remote server.

As a workaround, remove the `Web server URL` and [configure a local PHP interpreter](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/configuring-local-interpreter.html) at *Settings | PHP*. At the moment, you probably don't have it configured and get the 502 error because of that.

Related request on our tracker: [WI-60573](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-60573/Option-to-use-the-built-in-web-server-for-Built-in-Preview-when-a-default-deployment-configuration-is-specified)

Comment: I have left this topic already, but still thanks. I will def try it.